# AdBlock: How to block example.com and example.com/index but NOT all other example.com/*

Tags: exception, filter, adblock

I'd like to :

1. Block `example.com` and `example.com/index`. So I used:
   `||example.com|` along with `||example.com/index`
2. Have any offshoot except for index from example.com be available (i.e. `example.com/*` all available, but NOT `example.com` **and** `example.com/index`).

Working with this code in AdGuard / AdblockPlus.

I've never worked with this type of code, but I was unable to find a solution by searching. Hopefully I'm not being redundant.

Comment: Unless you're trying to hide a specific **element** on `example.com`, this is not in any way linked to CSS.

Comment: Are you talking about adding a rule to Adblock plus which hides HTML elements _from_ example.com?

Comment: @Beejamin no. I'm not trying to hide particular HTML elements, just outright pages. I want to hide/block example.com and example.com/index but **not** all other pages from example.com*

Answer (score 2):

According to the filter cheatsheet for AdBlock Plus: https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet#blocking, you should be able to achieve this with the following rules:

```
||example.com^      //Block everything at example.com
@@||example.com/^   //Exception for everything at example.com/*
||example.com/index //Re-block example.com/index
```

It's a shame that it needs to be 3 rules. There's a filter option for `domains` which can include/exclude domains, but [no option for a whole address](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#options) (which would eliminate the need for the 3rd rule).